# How to find minimum records that have unique values in 2 different columns

Tags: oracle

I have a table, say `TABLE_X` that has a unique value pair across 2 columns.  (See attached image)  However, I would like to minimize this result where I have at least **one** value from each of the columns.  Look at the table below.  There are 4 unique Letters in `COL_1` and 6 unique numbers in `COL_2`.  I've displayed a couple different solutions that show that every value in each column is represented somehow.  I'm not looking for any specific result other than making sure that all values are represented.
Is there some sort of function or `JOIN` I can do in SQL that will help accomplish this? I tried using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function but this didn't quite work as I couldn't get representation for **both** columns.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of *stupid*, but kind of *works*.

```
SQL> with test (col1, col2) as
  2    (select 'A', 1 from dual union all
  3     select 'A', 2 from dual union all
  4     select 'A', 5 from dual union all
  5     select 'A', 6 from dual union all
  6     select 'B', 1 from dual union all
  7     select 'B', 3 from dual union all
  8     select 'B', 5 from dual union all
  9     select 'C', 2 from dual union all
 10     select 'C', 3 from dual union all
 11     select 'C', 4 from dual union all
 12     select 'C', 5 from dual union all
 13     select 'D', 2 from dual
 14    ),
 15  inter as
 16    (select col1, min(col2) col2 from test group by col1
 17     union
 18     select min(col1) col1, col2 from test group by col2
 19    )
 20  select col1, max(col2) col2 from inter group by col1
 21  union
 22  select max(col1) col1, col2 from inter group by col2;

C       COL2
- ----------
A          5
A          6
B          1
B          3
C          4
D          2

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Not stupid, but kind of brilliant.  Thank you.  That worked perfect for my larger set of data.

Answer (score 0):

```
with 
  t(c1, c2, path) as (
    select col_1, col_2, cast(col_1 as varchar2(1000)) from table_x where col_2 = 1 
    union all 
    select col_1, col_2, path||' - '||col_1 
      from table_x join t on col_2 = c2 + 1 ),
  s as (select t.*, row_number() over (order by path) sn from t where c2 = 6),
  d as (
    select sn, t.c1, t.c2, s.path, count(distinct t.c1) over (partition by sn) cnt
      from s join t on s.path like t.path||'%')
select * from d where cnt = 4 order by sn, c2
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6dc7244edf2030e18f6fb5ac61b5a81c)</sup>**

- `t` - recursive query generating all possible solutions from your data, here solutions are built as `A - D - B - C - A - A` etc.
- `s` - `t` with added solution number `sn`
- `d` - `s` joined with `t` (to unpivot data) and added count of every distinct letter in solution

Finaly I select only solutions containing all four letters. There are 10 possible solutions in this particular case, take whichever you want.

You can do it on any set of data, there can be strings, numbers etc., but at first you have to assign them numbers (with row_number()) to allow recursive query work. And in this case in query you have to join solutions with original data using these identifiers.

Also here I hardcoded `6` (numbers) and `4` (letters), but you can easily count them at first.